# Phonegap LocalNotification Plugin 0.7.4 notifications keep appearing every time app launches

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

**What I want to achieve**

I want to be able to send a notification to the device, daily, by a specific time. Example: user should be notified at 3pm their local time every day.

**What I have done so far**

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {

            var notify = new Date();
            notify.setHours(15,00,00,00);

    window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id : 1,
            message : "please read your first verse of the day",
            title: "Verse 1",
            repeat: "daily",
            date: notify,
            autoCancel: true
        });
    };
```

**What the problem is:**

The notification shows up at 3pm and every time I launch the app after that, the notification appears on launch. Furthermore, notification doesn't repeat daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. No longer an issue. I just placed the code inside an if statement that allows the code inside it to be executed only the first time application loads.